# How to get predicates by specifying the number of arguments it should have?

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have these relations:

```
d(m, n).
d(x, y).
d(a, b, c).
d(i, j, k).
d(1, 2, 3, 4).
```

How can I write a predicate `mypred(Pred, NumArgs, Rel)`?

Examples:

1. `mypred(d, 2, Rel)`: `Rel` would be `d(m, n)`, `d(x, y)`, `false`.
2. `mypred(d, 3, Rel)`: `Rel` would be `d(a, b, c)`, `d(i, j, k)`, `false`.
3. `mypred(d, 4, Rel)`: `Rel` would be `d(1, 2, 3, 4)`, `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
mypred(F, A, Rel_0) :-
   functor(Rel_0, F, A),
   call(Rel_0).
```

However, rather don't use such a definition.  Instead try to use `call/N` with `N > 1`.

Definitions as mypred/3, are very difficult to analyze.  Cross-referencing is practically impossible.  On the other hand, with `call/N, N > 1` quite similar functionality is possible, cross-referencing stays intact. See [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) for many uses.